# Is there a residue theorem for Quaternions?

Tags: complex-analysis, quaternions

One of Complex Analysis's biggest contributions is the residue theorem. Is there a similar theorem in the field of Quaternion Analysis?

(A glance at Wikipedia didn't pull anything that caught my eye)

Comment: If there is you should be able to find it in [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0209166v1.pdf). Note that the correct definition of a quaternion holomorphic function is that it satisfies a certain version of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, not that the limit $\lim_{h \to 0} h^{-1}(f(x+h)-f(x)$ exists. That paper proves that such functions are actually linear, IIRC.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. It was mentioned, in passing, in an article I read once, about mathematical concepts being rediscovered. The author spoke about how he and his friends asked themselves that same question in their youth, came to a negative conclusion $($about its existence, or usefulness, or both$)$, and published it... only to later be proven wrong, when they found out that the concept actually did exist, and has already been discovered several decades before, and was not only quite useful, but that generalizations to even higher dimensions also existed $($sedenions, etc.$)$

Comment: @Lucian Cool, you said that it's been generalized to even higher dimensions. If it could be generalized to some kind of infinite dimensional space, it might be applicable to functional integration. Thanks :)